# Чтение памяти модуля DLL по указателям и смещению

Tags: c++, dll, память

Нашел модуль и смещения в приложении с помощью ARTMoney[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь получить это значение у себя:

```
hWnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "Clamp Champ");
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd,&pid); // запоминаем номер в переменную pid
        if (process == NULL && pid != 0) 
        process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, false, pid);
        unsigned int val = NULL;
        unsigned int val1 = NULL;
        unsigned int val2 = NULL;
        unsigned int val3 = NULL;

        ReadProcessMemory(process, (LPCVOID)(GetModuleBase("server.dll", pid )+0x215E950), &val1, 4, NULL);
        val1 = val1+0x2F8;
        ReadProcessMemory(process, (LPVOID)(val1), &val2, 4, NULL);
        val2 = val2+0x18;
        ReadProcessMemory(process, (LPVOID)(val2), &val3, 4, NULL);


        this->label1->Text = Convert::ToString(val3);
```

Вот так получаю базовый адрес

```html
    DWORD GetModuleBase(LPSTR lpModuleName, DWORD dwProcessId)
{
MODULEENTRY32 lpModuleEntry = {0};
HANDLE hSnapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, dwProcessId );
if(!hSnapShot)
return NULL;
lpModuleEntry.dwSize = sizeof(lpModuleEntry);
BOOL bModule = Module32First( hSnapShot, &lpModuleEntry );
while(bModule)
{
if(!strcmp( lpModuleEntry.szModule, lpModuleName ) )
{
CloseHandle( hSnapShot );
return (DWORD)lpModuleEntry.modBaseAddr;
}
bModule = Module32Next( hSnapShot, &lpModuleEntry );
}
CloseHandle( hSnapShot );
return NULL;
}
```

Выдает отличающиеся значения от artmoney! Ребят, может свежим взглядом кто найдет ошибки?

Comment: Есть предположение, что Artmoney выдает вам VA, а не RVA. 0x215E950 говорит скорее в пользу этой версии: вряд ли у вас модуль такой большой...

Comment: Модуль на самом деле очень большой, Я ковыряю память популярной  современной игры